# Appsrc is stuck in preroll even when sending EOS

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

Application has a pipeline:

`appsrc is-live=true ! audiorate skip-to-first=true tolerance=250000000 ! opusenc ! oggmux ! filesink`

The `gst_element_send_event(appsrc, gst_event_new_eos())` is called to terminate it. But the EOS sometimes doesn't get to the bus of the pipeline.

When it's not getting through, the callstack of the loop that has to deliver the EOS is instead stuck in waiting for a preroll:

```
g_cond_wait () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
gst_base_sink_wait_preroll () at gstbasesink.c:2212
gst_base_sink_do_preroll () at gstbasesink.c:2306
gst_base_sink_do_sync () at gstbasesink.c:2508
gst_base_sink_chain_unlocked () at gstbasesink.c:3495
gst_base_sink_chain_main () at gstbasesink.c:3656
gst_pad_chain_data_unchecked () at gstpad.c:4188
gst_pad_push_data () at gstpad.c:4440
in gst_pad_push () at gstpad.c:4559
in gst_proxy_pad_chain_default () at gstghostpad.c:126
in gst_pad_chain_data_unchecked () at gstpad.c:4188
gst_pad_push_data () at gstpad.c:4440
in gst_pad_push () at gstpad.c:4559
in gst_base_src_loop () at gstbasesrc.c:2850
in gst_task_func () at gsttask.c:332
in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
in start_thread () at pthread_create.c:333
in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:109
```

The application has no data to put into appsrc because it's the part of the cleanup procedure.

GStreamer 1.8.3.

How to cancel that preroll and get a proper EOS on the bus so everything can be closed?

Comment: when you want to stop perform following steps:
[1] stop pushing the data to appsrc 
[2] send eos to oggmux (where you should get eos on bus)
[3] send eos to appsrc
The above will make sure everything is closed.

Comment: @PrabhakarLad, the bus where I'm getting EOS out is associated with the GstBin that holds everything. There is no oggmux in other variations of the pipeline (like 'appsrc ! srtenc ! filesink'). Is there anything special about the muxer?

Comment: Not sure what you meant, could you paste the code somewhere I could have a look, the muxer needs to finalize the file, or else it may screw up the headers, for example try this pipeline  : gst-launch-1.0 -v audiotestsrc wave=sine num-buffers=100 ! audioconvert ! opusenc ! oggmux ! filesink location=sineproper.ogg  and also this gst-launch-1.0 -v audiotestsrc wave=sine ! audioconvert ! opusenc ! oggmux ! filesink location=sine.ogg for second pipeline you need to hit ctrl C to stop. check the duration of both the files!